# In a Jenkins script, can I bind credentials inside a conditional expression?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a script to dictate whether a Jenkins step runs. This script needs credentials, which we access by calling `withCredentials`.

Here's a slightly reduced example:

```
stage('Sample test stage') {
  when {
    expression {
      withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'MY_CREDENTIALS_ID', usernameVariable: 'MY_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'MY_TOKEN')]) {
        return sh([returnStdout: true, script: 'node bin/my-script ${MY_TOKEN}']).trim().startsWith('success')
      }
    }
  }
  steps {
    echo 'I should only run when the script passes'
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Jenkins returns the error: "syntax error: bad substitution."

I'm assuming it's down to the syntax used when trying to pass in the credentials. I've tried a couple of variations, such as returning `withCredentials` and wrapping the whole expression in `withCredentials`, but both of them had fairly dramatic errors.

I cannot find any documentation on this, which makes me wonder if it's illegal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel quite silly. There's a difference between `"` and `'` in Groovy. Within single quotes, only Bash substitutions will work. Within double quotes, both Groovy and Bash substitutions will work.